# Macro to transform non-tuple arguments to tuples

Tags: macros, rust

Is it possible to create a macro to transform non-tuple arguments to tuples? I would like something like this:

```
assert_eq!(tuplify!(1, (2, 3), 4), ((1,), (2, 3), (4,)));
```

I tried to create such macro but was unable to do so. The problem that I faced was that each argument can have one of two forms and I couldn't figure out how to specify it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If each argument to the macro is a single token tree, then this will do:

```
macro_rules! tuplify {
    (@inner ($($args:expr),*)) => (($($args,)*));
    (@inner $arg:expr) => (($arg,));
    ($($arg:tt),*) => (($(tuplify!(@inner $arg),)*));
}
```

What if arguments could have more than one token tree? For example:

```
assert_eq!(tuplify!(1 + 6, (2, 3), 4), ((7,), (2, 3), (4,)));
```

Then we just need to accept a sequence of token trees, right?

```
macro_rules! tuplify {
    (@inner ($($args:expr),*)) => (($($args,)*));
    (@inner $arg:expr) => (($arg,));
    ($($($arg_tt:tt)+),*) => (($(tuplify!(@inner $($arg)+),)*));
}
```

Nah, that would be too easy:

```
<anon>:12:30: 12:31 error: local ambiguity: multiple parsing options: built-in NTs tt ('arg_tt') or 1 other option.
<anon>:12     assert_eq!(tuplify!(1 + 6, (2, 3), 4), ((7,), (2, 3), (4,)));
```

It's ambiguous because `,` can also be parsed as a token tree.

In order to tackle this, I think we need to write a "[TT muncher](https://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/book/pat-incremental-tt-munchers.html)".

```
macro_rules! tuplify {
    (@as_expr $e:expr) => { $e };

    // No more tokens
    (@parse { } -> { $($current:tt)* } -> { $($output:tt)* }) => {
        tuplify!(@as_expr ( $($output)* ($($current)*,), ))
    };

    // Comma
    (@parse { , $($ts:tt)* } -> { $($current:tt)* } -> { $($output:tt)* }) => {
        tuplify!(@parse { $($ts)* } -> { } -> { $($output)* ($($current)*,), })
    };

    // Tuple followed by a comma, nothing in the current argument yet
    (@parse { ($($tuple_item:expr),*) , $($ts:tt)* } -> { } -> { $($output:tt)* }) => {
        tuplify!(@parse { $($ts)* } -> { } -> { $($output)* ($($tuple_item,)*), })
    };

    // Tuple followed by nothing else, nothing in the current argument yet
    (@parse { ($($tuple_item:expr),*) } -> { } -> { $($output:tt)* }) => {
        tuplify!(@parse { } -> { } -> { $($output)* ($($tuple_item,)*), })
    };

    // Base case
    (@parse { $t:tt $($ts:tt)* } -> { $($current:tt)* } -> { $($output:tt)* }) => {
        tuplify!(@parse { $($ts)* } -> { $t $($current)* } -> { $($output)* })
    };

    // Entry point
    ($($tokens:tt)*) => (tuplify!(@parse { $($tokens)* } -> { } -> { }));
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(tuplify!(1 + 6, (2, 3), 4), ((7,), (2, 3), (4,)));
}
```

Comment: Second time I see `@inner` and `@parse` in as many days, I need to go ahunting.

Comment: I'm just following the [convention](https://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/book/pat-internal-rules.html). :)